# Radix Sort Java

Tags: java, radix-sort

Welcome. I have a radix sorting method that uses an array to go through, but has to have another array (bin) that will store in an empty queue. I am confused as to how I would make a queue for the bins. I also have a findPlace method that finds the place of the each digit when called upon. So, here is what I got. Can someone help me find what I am missing? Thanks so much for your time.

```
public static void radix(int [] list){
       int [] bin = new int[10]; 
      ArrayQueue<Integer> part = new ArrayQueue<Integer>(); // EDIT What would I do with this queue?? 
      int num = 0; 
         for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++)
         {
            bin[i] = 0;  
          }

            for(int pass=0;pass<list.length;pass++)
           {
                for(int num=0;num<list.length;num++)
               {
                       int digit=findPlace(bin[pass], num);
                 }

                  bin[digit].add(list[num]); // add to the bin
            }
              // Put back into list
               for(int h=0; h<10; h++)
               {
                    while(!bin[h].isEmpty())
                    {
                       list[num] = bin[queueNum].remove();
                     num++;
                    }
              }
        }


public static int getPlace (int x, int place)
    {return x/place % 10;}
```

I also made a method to find the bucket, So i just need to know how I would put it into an array, would I just do this? part.add(getPlace(x, place));?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array, `bin` doesn't act like a queue just because you want it to :) Arrays don't have methods like `add()` and `remove()`. You have two choices on how to fix this:

- Program in the proper handling for queues yourself: A queue consists of an array and two pointers  into that array, traditionally called `head` and `tail`. You'd have to write your own methods to add and remove, which would work with the array and the pointers and take care of an empty queue or an overflowing one.
- Use Java's built-in Queue class. It's documented in the library's Javadocs. Don't know if your assignment intends for you to build your own queue, though.

**Update** with another detail:

You asked how to extract a single digit from a number. It's easiest working from the least significant digits (LSD) as suggested in the Wikipedia article. To do that:

- To extract the last digit, do `digit = number % 10` (that's the modulo operation). You will get an integer between 0 and 9 inclusive.
- To strip off the last digit, simply divide by 10. Then you can pull off another digit.
- Since you'll need to be looking at the n-th last digit of a number several times, you would do well to put this functionality into a separate method.

You can use your 0 thru 9 to select the right queue to put your number on.

When you've finished queueing all your numbers into the 10 buckets, you need to copy them from there back into a single list. Then repeat as long as there are still digits in any number that you haven't processed.

Comment: Yeah, you'd have to initialize the queue in your sorting method; it's probably a good idea to create the queue right there too. As for your algorithm, it looks wrong, but I'm not clever enough to say what it should look like.

Comment: Well, I read the Wikipedia entry and found a section there on how to do radix sort using queues <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#Iterative_version_using_queues> . According to that, you need not 1 but 10 queues. Have you read the description (or been given another description) and figured out what you need to do?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to do your homework for you. Whatever you're using for a queue, make an array of 10 of them. Also, see answer update, above.

Comment: Where's this Array queue class you were talking about earlier? A decent queue implementation will have methods like add() and remove() you can use.

Comment: I'm going to bed. Put up another question saying you need someone to talk you through implementing a radix sort for homework, with the extra challenge of very weak programming and problem solving skills on your side.